# Handler().postDelayed is now deprecated. What function to call instead?

Tags: android, kotlin

I use this function to delay the `notifyDatasetChanged()` function.

```
Handler().postDelayed({
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}, 100)
```

`Handler().postDelayed` is now deprecated. What function to call instead ?

In the documentation, Google says :

> This constructor is deprecated. Implicitly choosing a Looper during
> Handler construction can lead to bugs where operations are silently
> lost (if the Handler is not expecting new tasks and quits), crashes
> (if a handler is sometimes created on a thread without a Looper
> active), or race conditions, where the thread a handler is associated
> with is not what the author anticipated. Instead, use an Executor or
> specify the Looper explicitly, using Looper#getMainLooper, {link
> android.view.View#getHandler}, or similar. If the implicit thread
> local behavior is required for compatibility, use new
> Handler(Looper.myLooper(), callback) to make it clear to readers.

But I am a beginner and I don't speak English language well enough, and I can't understand if there is an other option to replace `handler()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the [constructor with an explicit looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#Handler(android.os.Looper)), for the Main thread Looper use `Looper.getMainLooper()`

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}, 100)
```

Answer (score -4):

I highly recommend to use [Kotlin Coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines) for that. After you Implemented the library into your project, this is the example code of Coroutines:

```
      GlobalScope.launch {
          delay(2000)
          "Your Code"
      }
```